# mdadm set the mode before a second device raid1?

Tags: centos, software-raid, mdadm, raid1

i have a problem. server use two disk softraid1. disk sda is die, and replaced disk. and reboot now, copy partition table sdb to sda ok. next step copy boot record sdb to sda ok. finaliy add sda in raid array retunr always error. error text : An option must be given to set the mode before a second device (/dev/md0) is listed. Watch command history. Please help me how to fix this problem. mdadm –manage /dev/md0 –add /dev/sda1 command not work. what should I do

```
root@rescue ~ # sfdisk -d /dev/sdb | sfdisk /dev/sda
Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ...
Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.
OK

Disk /dev/sda: 364801 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track

sfdisk: ERROR: sector 0 does not have an msdos signature
 /dev/sda: unrecognized partition table type
Old situation:
No partitions found
New situation:
Units = sectors of 512 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot    Start       End   #sectors  Id  System
/dev/sda1          2048  16779264   16777217  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2      16781312  17829888    1048577  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3      17831936 2165315584 2147483649  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda4     2165317632 5860533167 3695215536   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5     2165319680 5860531120 3695211441  fd  Linux raid autodetect
Warning: partition 1 does not end at a cylinder boundary
Warning: partition 2 does not start at a cylinder boundary
Warning: partition 2 does not end at a cylinder boundary
Warning: partition 3 does not start at a cylinder boundary
Warning: partition 3 does not end at a cylinder boundary
Warning: partition 4 does not start at a cylinder boundary
Warning: partition 4 does not end at a cylinder boundary
Warning: partition 5 does not end at a cylinder boundary
Warning: no primary partition is marked bootable (active)
This does not matter for LILO, but the DOS MBR will not boot this disk.
Successfully wrote the new partition table

Re-reading the partition table ...

If you created or changed a DOS partition, /dev/foo7, say, then use dd(1)
to zero the first 512 bytes:  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/foo7 bs=512 count=1
(See fdisk(8).)
root@rescue ~ # fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x55555555

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    16779264     8388608+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2        16781312    17829888      524288+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3        17831936  2165315584  1073741824+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda4      2165317632  5860533167  1847607768    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5      2165319680  5860531120  1847605720+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0006abe2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    16779264     8388608+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2        16781312    17829888      524288+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3        17831936  2165315584  1073741824+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb4      2165317632  5860533167  1847607768    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5      2165319680  5860531120  1847605720+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md0: 8589 MB, 8589869056 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 2097136 cylinders, total 16777088 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table
Disk /dev/md1: 536 MB, 536805376 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 131056 cylinders, total 1048448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
Disk /dev/md2: 1099.5 GB, 1099511431168 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 268435408 cylinders, total 2147483264 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Disk /dev/md2 doesn't contain a valid partition table
Disk /dev/md3: 1891.9 GB, 1891948101632 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 461901392 cylinders, total 3695211136 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Disk /dev/md3 doesn't contain a valid partition table

root@rescue ~ # dd if=/dev/sdb of=sdb.part bs=1024k count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.0158913 s, 66.0 MB/s

root@rescue ~ # dd if=sdb.part of=/dev/sda bs=1024k count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.00358636 s, 292 MB/s

root@rescue ~ # cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md3 : active raid1 sdb5[2]
      1847605568 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

md2 : active raid1 sdb3[2]
      1073741632 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

md1 : active raid1 sdb2[2]
      524224 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

md0 : active raid1 sdb1[2]
      8388544 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

unused devices: <none>

root@rescue ~ # mdadm –manage /dev/md0 –add /dev/sda1
mdadm: An option must be given to set the mode before a second device
       (/dev/md0) is listed
```

Comment: `-M` or `--manage`. Not `-manage`. (Check the number of `-` characters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok im found problem. right command :

```
mdadm /dev/md0 -a /dev/sda1
```

not :

```
mdadm –manage /dev/md0 –add /dev/sda1
```

and finally working on !

```
root@rescue ~ # cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md3 : active raid1 sda5[3] sdb5[2]
      1847605568 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]
        resync=DELAYED

md2 : active raid1 sda3[3] sdb3[2]
      1073741632 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]
      [>....................]  recovery =  4.8% (52262208/1073741632) finish=88.1min speed=193162K/sec

md1 : active raid1 sda2[3] sdb2[2]
      524224 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[3] sdb1[2]
      8388544 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: The problem that led me here came from copying and pasting a command I found on the web. The version on the web had something that looked like, but wasn't, ASCII 45 before the "create" mode.